# Hover Status Color Change, Avada Theme, Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, textcolor

We are using the Avada theme on a wordpress website: http://skybox.wearetechnology.com/

We would like to change the hover status of the links on our site, right now they go to white and the client has requested a white background.

I have tried to change the CSS to reflect this but somewhere in the theme settings they have the a:hover state coded into an embedded style sheet with the !important code at the end.

I can't find anywhere in the theme settings that allow to change to hover state color (even though you can change just about any other color).

Is there a way to override the code so that I can change the color back to a more visible color?

Right now I am using a text shadow and a stroke but it doesn't look very good.

Comment: You can see the links in the footer of the home page under recent news.

Answer (score 3):

If you make a CSS selector more specific than the one with the `!important` annotation, you should be able to override the hover color as long as you include an `!important` annotation of your own.

For example, this:

```
.featured-post a:hover {
    background-color: pink !important;
}
```

Will override this:

```
a:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

Here's [a simple JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MUd4b/). In the demo, the second link's styling overrides the `!important` annotation on the first due to having a more specific selector.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I found that in the Avada Theme there is a place in the backend under Theme Options to add custom code that overides any of the theme's CSS.

Answer (score 1):

This is the CSS I had to add in Avada custom css to remove the hover state color in Avada 4.0.1:

```
/* Undoes very specific css with an important clause from the author of the   theme */
.fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-link-icon-hover     .heading h2, body .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-  link-icon-hover .heading .heading-link h2, body .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-   content-box-hover .link-area-box-hover .heading h2, body .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-box-hover .heading .heading-link h2, body .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-link-icon-hover.link-area-box .fusion-read-more, body .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-link-icon-hover.link-area-box .fusion-read-more::after, body .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-link-icon-hover.link-area-box .fusion-read-more::before, body .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .fusion-read-more:hover:after, body .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .fusion-read-more:hover:before, body .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .fusion-read-more:hover, body .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-box-hover.link-area-box .fusion-read-more, body .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-box-hover.link-area-box .fusion-read-more::after, body .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-box-hover.link-area-box .fusion-read-more::before, body .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-link-icon-hover .icon .circle-no, body .fusion-content-boxes-1 .fusion-content-box-hover .link-area-box-  hover .icon .circle-no {
    color: black !important;
}
```